# Symfony 3 form with multiple databases always uses default entity manager

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entitymanager

I have recently created an admin application to manage all our users, customers etc...

The application is configured with 2 entitymanagers to get and set data to a 'staging' database and a 'production' database.

All fine, fetching data from the different databases is no problem but when a form is submitted, it always takes the default entity manager to validate and save the information entered.

Can I specify somewhere which entity manager should be used by a form on creation or at `$form->handleRequest($request);` ?

Config:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
        default:
            driver:   pdo_mysql
            host:     '%database_host%'
            port:     '%database_port%'
            dbname:   '%database_name2%'
            user:     '%database_user2%'
            password: '%database_password2%'
            charset:  UTF8
        prod:
            driver:   pdo_mysql
            host:     '%database_host%'
            port:     '%database_port%'
            dbname:   '%database_name%'
            user:     '%database_user%'
            password: '%database_password%'
            charset:  UTF8
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    default_entity_manager: staging
    entity_managers:
        staging:
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            connection: default
            mappings:
                AppBundle: ~
        prod:
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            connection: prod
            mappings:
                AppBundle: ~
```

CustomerController@CreateAction:

```
public function createAction(Request $request, $id, RegistryInterface $registry, $_env)
{
    $em = $registry->getManager($_env);
    $customer = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Customer')->find($id);

    $customer->init($this->getUser());

    $form = $this->createForm(CustomerForm::class, $customer, ['action' => $this->generateUrl('customers_edit', ['id' => $id, '_env' => $_env]), 'trait_choices' => [$em]]);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
```

I can't find a word on this subject in the docs of Symfony...

**EDIT**

CustomerType code:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\Entity\Role;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class CustomerType extends AbstractType
{
public function init($em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    if (isset($options['trait_choices'])) {
        call_user_func_array(array($this, 'init'), $options['trait_choices']);
    }

    $builder->add('companyName', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'label.name',
        'required' => true
    ]);
    $builder->add('street', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'label.street',
        'required' => true
    ]);
    $builder->add('streetNr', NumberType::class, [
        'label' => 'label.street_nr',
        'required' => true
    ]);
    $builder->add('streetBox', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'label.street_box',
        'required' => false
    ]);
    $builder->add('postalCode', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'label.postal_code',
        'required' => true
    ]);
    $builder->add('city', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'label.city',
        'required' => true
    ]);
    $builder->add('country', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Country',
        'choice_label' => 'name',
        'label' => 'label.country',
        'required' => true,
        'choice_translation_domain' => 'messages',
        'em' => $this->em
    ]);
    $builder->add('vatNr', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'label.vat',
        'required' => false
    ]);
    $builder->add('phone', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'label.phone',
        'required' => false
    ]);
    $builder->add('email', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'label.email',
        'required' => true
    ]);
    $builder->add('roles', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => Role::class,
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('r')
                ->where('r.type = ?1')
                ->setParameter(1, Role::TYPE_CUSTOMER);
        },
        'label' => 'Roles',
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true,
        'choice_label' => 'displayName',
        'attr' => [
            'class' => 'roles'
        ],
        'choice_translation_domain' => 'messages',
        'em' => $this->em
    ]);
    $builder->add('leadSources', EntityType::class, [
        'label' => 'label.origin_lead',
        'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\LM\LeadSource',
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true,
        'choice_label' => 'name',
        'choice_translation_domain' => 'messages',
        'em' => $this->em
    ]);

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, array($this, 'onPreSubmitListener'));
}

public function onPreSubmitListener(FormEvent $event)
{
    $customer = $event->getForm()->getData();
    if ($customer->getIdentifier() == null) {
        $customer->setIdentifier(uniqid('dummy'));
        $event->getForm()->setData($customer);
    } else {
        $event->getForm()->setData($customer);
    }
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Customer',
        'trait_choices' => null,
        'allow_extra_fields' => true,

    ]);
}
}
```

Comment: Did you looks to the [Symfony Doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html) ? You have 3 way to get the right manager. Second are you sure of the $_env value ? 
And why you don't put your registry and $env in your controller constructor ?

Comment: I'm very sure about the value of $_env because I get the right data on all the 'index' routes where I show the database entries. Maybe I should move them to my controller constructor, didn't think about that. But that can't be the solution to my problem I guess...

Comment: According to your posted code you are passing trait_choices as an array [$em] which indicates your init is not working.  And you are not showing where the $em is actually being used.  Is it an EntityType?  If so then make sure you set the em option: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#em

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How is the value for $_env injected? Try to dump it to see that it actually returns what you expect it to return ("prod" or "staging")

The behavior you experience implies that it is probably always null, so the default entity manager is created in all cases.

Try something like
$env = $container->getParameter("kernel.environment")

PS
Your use of environments is a bit weird. It is probably not such a good idea to risk accessing your prod db from your dev or staging environments.
Try to use the parameters and .env files as they should be used.

UPDATE:

You can pass an entity manager to your form type, using the options array when you call the createForm function

Something like

```
$form = $this->createForm(
     YourFormType::class,
     $yourEntity,
     [
         'entityManager' => $this->getDoctrine()->getManager($_env),
     ]
);
```

And then in your buildForm function you can retrieve it from the options array.

UPDATE 2

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'entityManager' => null,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: A dump of my $_env variable is 'prod'. It's set as a prefix variable in the url. So that's not the problem, the returned entitymanager is also the right one, it's just the form that's taking the wrong entity manager...

Ps: On my dev or staging environments it's not possible to acces the prod db, it's only the other way around, from production you can create a 'staging' customer.

Comment: Ok. You can pass an entity manager to your type, using the options array  when you call createForm.
I will update my answer with some code

Comment: My entityManager is currently passed to the form, I use it 3 times for the choicefields, so that's already done, no?

Comment: True. Sorry I missed that. But why use that weird call_user_func_array and not just initialize the property on the constructor?

Comment: There is also an option to reset the default manager to null, but I cannot find it now. I will post when I find it

Comment: Got it. Updated my response. The code should be more clear there

Try adding this to your CustomerType

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'entityManager' => null,
        ]);
    }

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help here! Passing the entitymanager like that indeed did the job.

Comment: Hello, I don't understand how you solved this problem.
How passing *entityManager* in options solved this ? I'm missing a step.

Comment: I don't get it, exactly how did you solved it?